# Using SortNoop in BibTeX produces different Biblabel

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I use `@PREAMBLE{"\def\SortNoop#1{}"}` in my BIB file to get the sorting of `AUTHOR = {{\SortNoop{Bruijn}}de Bruijn, Nicolaas Govert}` right. But this changes the label of the bibitem: All other entries with only one author have a label where the last name of the author is abbreviated with three alphabetic characters. The one using `\SortNoop` has the label [B64], but I would expect something like [Bru64] or [deB64]. How do I get the label [Bru64]?

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@PREAMBLE{"\def\SortNoop#1{}"}

@INCOLLECTION{Bruijn1964,
  AUTHOR = {{\SortNoop{Bruijn}}de Bruijn, Nicolaas Govert},
  TITLE = {{P{\'o}lya's} {Theory} of {Counting}},
  BOOKTITLE = {Applied combinatorial mathematics},
  PUBLISHER = {John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York-London-Sydney},
  YEAR = {1964}
}

@ARTICLE{Harary1958,
  AUTHOR = {Harary, Frank},
  TITLE = {On the number of bi-colored graphs},
  JOURNAL = {Pacific J. Math.},
  YEAR = {1958}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

The label of \cite{Harary1958} has three alphabetic characters in it.
But the label of \cite{Bruijn1964} has only one alphabetic character.
How do I get the label [Bru64] or [deB64]?

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong biblabel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hack to your hack. Or don't use the `alpha` style. `;-)`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@PREAMBLE{"\newcommand\SortNoop[1]{}"}
@PREAMBLE{"\newcommand\Bru{Bru}"}

@INCOLLECTION{Bruijn1964,
  AUTHOR = {{\SortNoop{Bruijn}}de {\Bru}ijn, Nicolaas Govert},
  TITLE = {{P{\'o}lya's} {Theory} of {Counting}},
  BOOKTITLE = {Applied combinatorial mathematics},
  PUBLISHER = {John Wiley and Sons, Inc., New York-London-Sydney},
  YEAR = {1964}
}

@ARTICLE{Harary1958,
  AUTHOR = {Harary, Frank},
  TITLE = {On the number of bi-colored graphs},
  JOURNAL = {Pacific J. Math.},
  YEAR = {1958}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

The label of \cite{Harary1958} has three alphabetic characters in it.
But the label of \cite{Bruijn1964} has only one alphabetic character.
How do I get the label [Bru64] or [deB64]?

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]